# Keeping SQLAlchemy sessions alive to GCP/Spanner

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

tl;dr: Is it a good idea to try to keep sessions alive to Spanner (GCP) (I'm thinking it's not, fwiw), and if so, what are some suggestions on how to configure the SQLAlchemy engine/sessionmaker to do this?

We've been using SQLAlchemy for quite a few years for a very small DB, in the classic setup - locally hosted. In it, we essentially store RBAC related data about users such that we can on the fly ensure user sessions have permissions to hit certain endpoints. This works quite well, and because the DB is local, holding sessions open for very long periods of time works fine. In the even of networking issues/closed sockets, we just catch the exception and open a new session, returning the old/stale one to the pool.

I've started playing with spanner recently, and am using an in-development SQLAlchemy dialect for it (it's working quite well). However, all connections are gRPC to Googles cloud, and thus sessions time out after 10 seconds. The cost of re-creating sessions appears to be quite high (very long waits [2-3 seconds] to initiate). This is clearly intended behavior, but I'm wondering if I've missed something with session management to Spanner, or if this is a usecase for trying to ensure that sqlalchemy keeps session alive.

Given the intended nature of the gRPC sessions, *am I just overlooking something that's causing such long delays during session creation?* Running manual queries via the CLI has the same issue of long latencies on initial query. The dataset in question is four tables, and KB's in size, so it's not a complexity or data size issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to clarify a confusion I've noted: Cloud Spanner sessions are not transactions.

A Spanner session represents a communication channel with the Cloud Spanner database service and can execute one transaction at a time. As you have correctly noted, creating new sessions is expensive which is why we cache sessions for reuse in session pools for the client libraries. However, a session is only cleaned up after one hour of inactivity.

More information about Spanner session management can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions#performance_benefits_of_a_session_cache

A Spanner transaction is aborted after 10 seconds of inactivity. This is because the transaction locks the whole table. It is possible to avoid this by periodically executing `SELECT 1` however this is not recommended unless you understand the drawbacks of keeping the transaction open.

As a note, we have a Cloud Spanner SQLAlchemy dialect that is currently in preview which can be found here:
https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/python-spanner-sqlalchemy

Comment: Ahhh alright, so I think the confusing bit in my OP was `However, all connections are gRPC to Googles cloud, and thus sessions time out after 10 seconds.` It sounds like this isn't true - _transactions_ time out after 10 seconds, but sessions are left alive for up to 1 hour.  Using SQLAlchemy and your library, do you have a recommended method of session management (eg: using a session pool), or am I over-thinking this and that's handled already with your lib? Obviously transactions need to be used tactfully to avoid locks/blocking (and transaction closed errors)

Comment: The `sqlalchemy-spanner` library found in the `python-spanner-sqlalchemy` repo linked above handles session and transaction management.

The `google-cloud-spanner` library found in the `python-spanner` repo should handle session management depending on how you are calling the library. The recommended usage of the library avoids session leaks by handling all session management for the user. However, this usage generally isn't suited for ORMs like SQLAlchemy. This is why I would recommend trying the above dialect.

Comment: @larkee @geudrik It seems you are, at least, up and running with the dialect in the `python-spanner-sqlalchemy` library.  I'm having issues just getting going.  While this is off-topic for the question at hand, could you look at this issue:

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095208/sqlalchemy-nosuchmoduleerror-cant-load-plugin-sqlalchemy-dialectsspanner