# SQLAlchemy NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:spanner

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-cloud-spanner

## Problem

We're trying to connect to Cloud Spanner via `SQLAlchemy` version `1.3.23` and [python-spanner-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy).  Using `Poetry` for dependency management, `sqlalchemy-spanner` has been added like so (this is how the project was set up):

```py
sqlalchemy = "~1.3"
sqlalchemy-spanner = { git="https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/python-spanner-sqlalchemy.git", tag="v0.1.0" }
```

When `create_engine` is called with

```py
create_engine("spanner:///projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/databases/my-db")
```

I get the following error

```py
class 'sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError'>", "NoSuchModuleError(\"Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:spanner\")
```

## Attempts

#### Registry

I've tried adding (as seen in the [`conftest.py`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/blob/main/test/conftest.py#L20) file in the python-spanner-sqlalchemy [test](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/blob/main/test/conftest.py#L20) package)

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry

registry.register("spanner", "google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner", "SpannerDialect")
```

before `create_engine` is called, which leads to the following error:

```py
class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>", "ModuleNotFoundError(\"No module named 'google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner'\")
```

This makes me think that the plugin dialect has not been correctly added since, in line 49 of [`setup.py`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy/blob/main/setup.py#L49), the connection for the dialect is made:

```py
entry_points={
    "sqlalchemy.dialects": [
        "spanner = google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner:SpannerDialect"
    ]
},
```

#### Installing via `python setup.py install`

In the [README](https://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy#installation) for the spanner project, it says to clone the repo and install via `python setup.py install`.  I performed this step, but am unsure how to import this into my current project or make my project aware of this library. I've never manually installed python packages before so, if anyone can provide any help here, I'd appreciate it.

What I *did* try:

- install the library as per above
- try to add the dependency via poetry : `poetry add sqlalchemy-spanner`.  Got `Could not find a matching version of package sqlalchemy-spanner`
- try to locate the library via pip : `pip install sqlalchemy-spanner==` which usually lists available package versions.

I'm not sure that either of the last 2 bullets actually check a local installation of a package.  Not even really sure what I'm talking about here.

## Update

- So I was able to install the local version of `python-spanner-sqlalchemy` by using `pip install /path/to/project`, which works, but still having the same issues with loading the dialect.
- I added an import for `SpannerDialect` in the code (in the Registry section) above with `from google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner import SpannerDialect`. PyCharm auto-completed this for me which indicates to me that the package is successfully installed and available.  But I receive the `ModuleNotFoundError` for `google.cloud.sqlalchemy_spanner` when running.
- I ran `python` in my project root directory and, from the repl, imported `SpannerDialect` with no errors.

## Solution

To clarify, the solution @larkee provided worked regarding the updated repository URL.

> As a note, we recently moved the repo from cloudspannerecosystem/python-spanner-sqlalchemy to googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy.

I clarified why that worked in the comments to their answer

I have not tested the answer from @neondot42, but I have seen this brought up as well, so take a look there if you're having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the error you are seeing by installing `sqlalchemy` but not having `sqlalchemy-spanner` installed at all:

```
pip install sqlalchemy==1.3
pip uninstall sqlalchemy-spanner
```

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine(<url>)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:spanner
```

After I install `sqlalchemy-spanner` I am able to use SQLAlchemy without issue:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy.git@v0.1.0
```

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, inspect
>>> engine = create_engine(<url>)
>>> metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
>>> table = Table(
...     "TestTable",
...     metadata,
...     Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
...     Column("user_name", String(16), nullable=False),
... )
>>> table.create()
>>> inspect(engine).get_table_names()
['TestTable']
>>>
```

Based on this, I think the issue is that `sqlalchemy-spanner` is not being installed. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with `Poetry` for dependency management so I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong. As a note, we recently moved the repo from `cloudspannerecosystem/python-spanner-sqlalchemy` to `googleapis/python-spanner-sqlalchemy`. I am able to use either for the `pip` command but perhaps `Poetry` requires the newer one?

Comment: I tried installing via `pip` with that url, but am getting an error regarding issues with the `CONTRIBUTING.md` and `contributing.md` files clashing.  `Poetry` is also failing install (with an obscure message) which I assume is because of the same issue?

Comment: I agree that the `Poetry` failure is likely related to the `pip` installation failure. Would you be able to give more information such as your `pip` version, OS, and the error you are getting?

You are welcome to open an issue over on the `python-spanner-sqlalchemy` repo if that's easier.

Comment: I changed to the new url, blew away all docker containers and images, re-provisioned and it's working now.  I think my docker image was not being rebuilt after the addition of the new url dependency.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for the late response. I was recently struggling with a similar problem. Sqlalchemy was unable to load the spanner dialect. I tried uninstalling and installing different versions with pip but nothing seemed to work.

At the end what did the trick was specifying the "driver" part of the database URL as "spanner" too. So the final URL looked like this:

```
spanner+spanner:///projects/project-id/instances/instance-id/databases/database-id
```

I am not entirely sure of why this appeared to be the solution for me, as all the documentation I could find on Google's end just showed that you could use only the "spanner:///..." to connect. Also I am not familiar with the inner workings of sqlalchemy and how it should detect other installed dialects. However, I hope this solution can help someone else.

Comment: this worked for me too. Any idea why this occurs?